# Applescript file dialog with UI scripting

Tags: applescript

I am trying to open a file in a not so scriptable area of an application.

I got halfway there by using UI scripting to select the proper menu item, but this opens a standard file dialog.

How can I set the destination of the file dialog with Applescript?

Comment: what app is it can we see what you have tried  ?

Comment: Safari, the import bookmarks dialog under file. So far I have done nothing more than a simple click "item" of "menu" of "bar", or something similar, which is working fine.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Import bookmarks into Safari? If so, you're better off importing the .plist directly into the user's directory rather than going through Safari's GUI.

Comment: How would I do the plist thing? That sounds good...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ahh ok  this should get you going on the right path

```
   tell application "Safari"
    activate
    -- do menu select gui script first
    set posixpath to "/path/to/a/folder/that/exists"
    tell window 1
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}
            keystroke posixpath
            delay 1
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
   end tell
```

Comment: I agree wiht songdogtech but this is how you set the destination folder