# Using AppleScript to choose a file in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I am trying to write some automation code (primarily in Ruby Selenium). At some point, a file chooser is opened in Safari so that the user can select a file for upload. Selenium cannot handle this, but I think AppleScript should be able to. I am new to AppleScript and haven't been able to find any boilerplate code of someone automating a file chooser dialog. I'm reading through the AppleScript docs, but any ideas would be most helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically tell Safari to upload a specific file once the file chooser is open, or to let Safari open a chooser in the first place?

Comment: The former. Selenium clicks a link which opens a Safari file chooser, I then call my AppleScript with the file location, and we're good. At least I hope so - just about to try it. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some more searching and I found a great answer here: [Applescript file dialog with UI scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473091/applescript-file-dialog-with-ui-scripting)

Here's what I ended up using:

```
on run argv
tell application "Safari"
    activate

    -- Usage check
    set argc to count argv
    if argc is not greater than 0 then
        return "Usage: SafariFileChooser file_name [window_name]"
    end if

    -- The file we will choose to open
    set file_name to item 1 of argv

    -- Flip to the named window, if specified
    if argc is equal to 2 then
        set window_name to item 2 of argv
        set flip_count to index of window window_name
        repeat (flip_count - 1) times
            activate
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke "`" using command down
        end repeat
    end if

    -- Interact with the dialog using System Events (thanks mcgrailm)
    tell front window
        activate
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down}
            keystroke file_name
            delay 1
            keystroke return
            delay 1
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
return 0
```

end run

Answer (score 0):

Another option I just discovered is to specify the directory using the command-line:

```
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.Safari NSNavLastRootDirectory /path/to/directory"
```

This way you can do slightly less in UI scripting. Run this command before you open the file chooser, and it will put you into the directory specified. Include all the files you need in this directory, and you can just script command+a to select them all, and return.