# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown command: uploadFile

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a file using Safari Driver.

Here is my code:

```
DesiredCapabilities browserCapabillities = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
RemoteWebDriver driver = new SafariDriver(browserCapabillities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("myAppURL");

WebElement upload = driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@id='fileElementId']");
RemoteWebElement webElement = ((RemoteWebElement) upload);

LocalFileDetector detector = new LocalFileDetector();
webElement.setFileDetector(detector);

File f = detector.getLocalFile("myFilePath");
upload.sendKeys(f.getAbsolutePath()); // Generating exception: 
    // org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown command: uploadFile

driver.findElement(By.id("uploadButton")).click();
```

Only thing that is working for me right now is AppleScript. Thanks to [Using AppleScript to choose a file in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170142/using-applescript-to-choose-a-file-in-safari). But with Apple Script I had to keep my machine unlocked.

I feel LocalFileDetector is a better solution as I would like to run my tests even when the machine is locked.

I am not sure whether the following helps ?

```
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector()); // I am getting
   // org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Setting the file detector only    
   // works on remote webdriver instances obtained via RemoteWebDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new SafariDriver(browserCapabillities);
```

to

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(urlofhub,browserCapabillities);
```

Refer [this](http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload) post for an example code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added hub. Now there is no exception. Still sendKeys is not updating the file path. Just fyi, I am using "Jasny's file upload with Bootstrap 3" component.